# How to pass a single form from dynamically generated forms? (AJAX , Spring)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a JSP page that generates all the available products in the database. Each product has a 'Add to cart' button. Here is my JSP code...

```
<body>
<c:forEach items="${inventories}" var="inventory" varStatus="varStatus">
    <form:form id="myForm"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/ajax"
        method="POST" modelAttribute="cartProduct">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="padding: 2%;">
            <div class="card">
                <form:input type="hidden" path="user.email"
                    value="${user.getEmail()}" />
                <form:input type="hidden" path="product.productId"
                    value="${inventory.getProduct().getProductId()}" />
                <div class="card-block" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 2%">
                    <h5 style="white-space: nowrap">
                        <a href="#" class="text-primary card-title">${inventory.getProduct().getName()}</a>
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-danger">&#8369;
                        ${inventory.getProduct().getPrice()}</p>
                    <p class="text-success">In stock</p>
                    <p>
                        <span style="">Added to cart</span>
                    </p>
                    <form:button class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Add to cart</form:button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</c:forEach>
</body>
```

And here is my AJAX code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var form = $("form");
var method = form.attr("method");
var url = form.attr("action");

form.on("submit", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : form.serialize(),
        type : "POST",
        success : function(smartphone) {
            console.log('success');     
        },
        error : function() {
            alert('Something went wrong')
        }
    });
});
});
```

This code generates an array of forms containing each product. However, whenever I click on a single product, the ajax code submits all of the products not the single one that I clicked. How can I submit the data from the form that I only clicked?

Comment: You say your `form` variable contains an array of all the products, then in your ajax you send `form.serialize()` which suggests sending the entire array. What happens when you send `$(this).serialize()`?

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you! This solved my problem. :) I'm a beginner in JavaScript so please forgive me for this question.

Comment: Not a problem. You were close. Sometimes it is just a matter of looking at it from the codes point of view ;).

Comment: I have another question @ja

Comment: Whats up with your 2. question?